# Неверная линковка проекта в Qt + msvc2010

Tags: c++, qt, сборка, линковка

Поддерживаю один проект, он используется в виде сервиса windows, реализован при помощи Qt ( класс `QtService` и пр. )
Перекидываю из папки bin установленного в Qt QtCore4.dll в папку прописанную в переменной среды PATH (установщик делает это автоматически)
Во время запуска сервиса программа вылетает с ошибкой:

```
Точка входа в процедуру _Z4endlR11QTextStream не найдена в библиотеке DLL Qt4Core.dll
```

Сборка - Release

Комплект Qt - на основе msvc2010
windows7 x86 64-bit.

Есть ли какой-то метод настроить линковщик?
Ведь он указывает в какой dll программе искать функции.
Понимаю, что можно попробовать пересобрать Qt, но не факт что это верное решение.

Кстати, при запуске через qtcreator\отладке со средой сборки проекта программа вылетает уже с ошибкой запуска сервиса, что намкает на то, что программа таки смогла подгрузить нужную функцию.

grep-нул по имени-представлению в runtime функции по dll файлам в bin, ни один файл не совпал.

Answer (score 0):

Если порыться в каталоге с Qt, то можно найти библиотеки, которые в папке bin - это для QtCreator, а можно ещё найти библиотеки для других компиляторов/версий (mingw  к примеру). Вам нужно скопировать эту библиотеку (и сопутствующие) с правильной версии kit. У Вас это будет скорее всего папка `C:\Qt\4???\msvc2010_64\bin`.

Но вот только перекладывать в папку, прописанную в PATH я бы тоже не стал. Таких "рекомендаций" много и все так прописывают. Если кто то с своим путем успел раньше - будет проблема, аналогична Вашей. Самое простое - положить себе под ноги (в ту же папку, где exe).

Но честно, 4 Qt - это такое устаревшее...

Comment: Нету там никаких специальных сборок dll

Comment: к сожалению, я не могу ставить 4 версию Qt - ее у меня уже ни один установщик не предлагает. Просто по всему компу поищите Qt4Core.dll и загляните им в свойста-версия. Там и прояснится

Comment: В общем, сделал debug сборку и кинул бинарник в сервис, все работает. А так, это проблема несовместной компоновки, нужно копать либо Makefile's к исходникам Qt, либо сами исходники Qt, чтобы собралась совместная dll. Либо все сразу.

Comment: Еще, конечно же, можно сделать статическую сборку либы, и на основе этой сборки делать релизы. Это, наверняка, из-за того, что версия бесплатная, чтобы нельзя было выпустить релиз на ее основе. Часто мне приходилось собирать Qt из исходников.